# What kind of adjective is "hot" in "He is hot"?

Tags: adjectives

In the sentence "He is hot", is the adjective "hot" a postpositive adjective, a qualifying adjective or another type of adjective? When reading about postpositive adjectives the examples given were things like "attorney general", "God almighty", "words unspoken" etc. In short, adjectives that directly follow the noun.

When reading about qualifying adjectives, examples were "The car is very old" which follows a verb just like "hot" does. However, I'm not totally sure.

What kind of adjective is "hot" in this sentence?

Comment: In your example, the AdjP "hot" is a 'subjective predicative complement' of "is". This is the 'ascriptive' use of the  verb "be" since the PC denotes a property that is ascribed to the referent of the predicand  - "he" in your example. Note that it is not a modifier as in "a hot child" or "matters financial", where "hot" and "financial" are respectively a premodifier and a postmodifier.

Comment: Semantically, "He is hot." has two meanings, one of which has the same grammar as explained above. There is also the song: Hot, Hot, Hot with similar ambiguity and meaning. [that's a  joke]

Answer (score 2):

The same as "He is cold", too. That would be a predicate adjective. Postpositive adjectives don't act as predicates in sentences, so may be used as parts of sentence fragments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> In your example, the AdjP "hot" is a 'subjective predicative complement' of "is". This is the 'ascriptive' use of the  verb "be" since the PC denotes a property that is ascribed to the referent of the predicand  - "he" in your example. Note that it is not a modifier as in "a hot child" or "matters financial", where "hot" and "financial" are respectively a premodifier and a postmodifier.